# Can't install matplotlib with pip in Python 3.9 64-bit?

Tags: python, module, pip

Error: Command errored out with exit status 1.

Can anybody help me out with getting matplotlib installed in the 64-bit version? It worked just fine for the 3.8 32-bit version I formerly had installed

Answer (score -1):

You could try upgrading pip.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```